# Pandas datetime64 to string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am converting pandas dataframe column of datetime64 to list and then exporting into single column of csv.

In CSV I get values as

```
"[Timestamp('2018-05-20 10:20:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-20 10:30:00')]"
```

How can I convert to string and export to CSV. I would like to have data as below:

```
['2018-05-20 10:20:00', '2018-05-20 10:30:00']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just cast the dtype first using `astype`:

```
In[29]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['2018-05-20 10:20:00','2018-05-20 10:30:00'])})
df

Out[29]: 
                 date
0 2018-05-20 10:20:00
1 2018-05-20 10:30:00

In[30]:
df['date'].astype(str).tolist()

Out[30]: ['2018-05-20 10:20:00', '2018-05-20 10:30:00']
```

What you did just converted the array to a list of the original dtype:

```
In[31]:
df['date'].tolist()

Out[31]: [Timestamp('2018-05-20 10:20:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-20 10:30:00')]
```

The more formal method is to call [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas.Series.dt.strftime) to convert to string using the passed in format:

```
In[33]:
df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()

Out[33]: ['2018-05-20 10:20:00', '2018-05-20 10:30:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

### EdChum's setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['2018-05-20 10:20:00','2018-05-20 10:30:00'])})
df

                 date
0 2018-05-20 10:20:00
1 2018-05-20 10:30:00
```

### `list` and `map`

```
list(map(str, df.date))

['2018-05-20 10:20:00', '2018-05-20 10:30:00']
```